# How to fetch all tags in the history of selected branch, but only those tags?

Tags: git, tags, fetch

## Premises

While the documentation of `git fetch` (Version 2.21.0) claims:

> By default, any tag that points into the histories being fetched is also fetched; the effect is to fetch tags that point at branches that you are interested in. This default behavior can be changed by using the ´--tags´ or ´--no-tags´ options or by configuring ´remote..tagOpt´. By using a refspec that fetches tags explicitly, you can fetch tags that do not point into branches you are interested in as well.

This is **not** the actual behaviour. Rather, when performing for example `git fetch origin master` *no* tags are fetched — the *actual* default is, as of 2.21.0, `--no-tags`, the documentation seems to be out of sync with the implementation. When specifying `--tags` *all* tags are fetched, also those which are on non-merged branches (i.e. not in the history of `origin/master`).

## Question

**Are there any settings to actually force the behaviour as described in the docs, i.e. specifying that I am interested in a certain branch (`origin/master` in the example) and to not only fetch all commits and the head, but also all tags which are pointing to the history of said branch?**

I was reading TFM and used my Google-fu (which might be lacking), but honestly didn't see a solution. Can you fine people help?

Answer (score 0):

Jeff King points out to [this discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/alpine.LSU.2.20.1910021431130.32588@cpza.bfz-tzou.qr/T/#u)

> - If I fetch without `--tags`, the tags that point to the commits of the 
>     fetched branch are not fetched.
> - If I fetch with `--tags`, then *all* tags are fetched.
>     But I only wish to fetch tags pointing to something in the branch fetched.

Jeff adds:

> It's a documentation bug, I think.
>   We won't auto-follow tags when fetching into `FETCH_HEAD` (but this is further confused by the fact that fetching into `FETCH_HEAD` will auto-update a tracking ref).
>
> So instead of this:
>
> ```
> $ git fetch origin master
> ```
>
> try this:
>
> ```
> $ git fetch origin
> ```
>
> or even this:
>
> ```
> $ git fetch origin master:refs/remotes/origin/master
> ```

But:

> I thought it would work, but it works only once. On the second time the 
>   ref for the remote branch is deleted. It seems Git is confused by 
>   specifying a ref it expect to manage itself.
>
> Is there any other way to force auto-follow tags?
>
> It seems like a bad interaction with `fetch.prune` (I don't have it set,
>   and the problem doesn't appear, but if I set it, I can reproduce your
>   issue).

See more in this [other discussion](https://public-inbox.org/git/20170817092853.hteuzni5lxia4ejf@sigill.intra.peff.net/):

> I think the problem is not that you have a refspec, but that your
>   refspec has no destination.
>
> Looking at the fetch code, we seem to turn on autotags only when the destination is a "real" ref and not just the default `FETCH_HEAD`.
>   Which sort-of makes sense. If you're doing a one-off into `FETCH_HEAD`, you probably don't want to create tags, even if you have the objects they point to.